# How could I avoid UV maps when combining procedural Textures?

Tags: materials, texturing, node-editor

I would like to have a transparent material like:

[image]

What I have so far is

[image]

How could I get rid of the *Texture Coordinate* and *Mapping* Nodes? (I just did this because I don't know better)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep them. UV Mapping is the default texture coordinate for image textures in Cycles, but the generated textures use generated coordinates by default:

> Texture coordinate to sample texture at; defaults to Generated texture
>   coordinates if the socket is left unconnected. (http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Nodes/Textures, **Wave Texture**)

You could simplify the setup if you pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to make the two nodes a group (a group looks like a single node). You can edit a group by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: One texture works fine, I only need the mapping to rotate the other texture. I was hoping that there is another node for rotation.

Comment: You could rotate your UVMap, but other than that, no there is no other rotate node.

Comment: @CharlesL You might be interested to know that PGmath has devised a custom rotation node. (Actually one node setup for each axis, but you can combine them.) See the answer [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40770/possible-to-control-a-driver-from-a-group-node-input-slider).