# How do you try different random seeds for noise texture node?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor

Using Blender 2.76 and cycles, I'm trying to color an object with the *Noise Texture* node, among others. The resulting object looks like this:

[image]

I'm happy with the basic colors, but I'd like to try different random seeds, to see different distributions of the green and blue.  But I don't see a field for such a seed on the node.

[image]

Is there a way to do this? I tried putting some things into the `Vector` input, but it only zeroed out the noise. I don't understand that input yet.

Comment: Check out my explanation of texture mapping [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23174/5705).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This doesn't really change the seed, but you can get a different noise pattern by translating the whole texture by a significant amount.

[image]

The Suzanne on the left uses a noise texture with default settings and mapping coordinates.  The Suzanne on the right uses the same noise texture, but uses the below nodes to shift the [texture coordinates](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23174/5705) to get a different noise pattern.

[image]

For the sake of space i am using my [homemade translate node](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/40829/5705) but you could just as well use a mapping node as well.

Comment: Perfect, that's what I was looking for. That's even better than a seed, actually, because you can make minor adjustments too.

Comment: You could introduce an object info -> random node to this setup, to have it, well, more random.

Comment: @MSchmits  The Object Info node's random output is per-object.  I believe the OP wants to manually adjust the seed to adjust the pattern on a single object.

Answer (score 3):

1. I added a node *Input > Object Info*,
2. and linked the *Random* value to the *Location* value of a *Vector > Mapping* node
3. Your texture UV (or simply Input > UV) goes into the *Mapping* node's *Vector* value,
4. and the output of the *Mapping* node goes into the *Vector* of my *Noise Texture*.

That worked very nicely and I didn't have to make my materials single user - just cloned my objects and it worked.

The *Random* output generates a value in the 0 - 1 range for each object.  If you want to increase the random range you can use a *Math > Multiply* node.