# is it possible to distort a voronoi texture like the wave textures distortion slider?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor

I want to distort a voronoi texture in a similar way to how the wave texture's distortion feature does, but there isn't any kind of built in slider for this like there is with the wave texture.

Is it possible to distort voronoi in a similar fashion?

Comment: is this the same question? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45875/how-to-mix-procedural-textures-for-a-natural-waves-of-sand-displacement-effect

Comment: Well, these two questions can help each other. However this very question is more about adding distortions on a procedural texture which doesn't have a distort option. And then it could be used for many things

Comment: somehow related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45167/how-to-create-a-procedural-chevron-like-texture-material/45169#45169

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use another texture to distort a texture. Depending on the value you affect you'll get different results:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Endless Fun!

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You can add some distortion to any texture by distorting its mapping coordinates.  Below I am using my [homemade versions of the mapping node](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40770/possible-to-control-a-driver-from-a-group-node-input-slider/40829#40829) since they have input sockets which I can easily plug a noise texture into to dynamically distort the map.  You could use the Separate/Combine XYZ nodes with some math nodes in-between to accomplish the same thing.

[image]

Just plug some [different noise textures](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44429/how-do-you-try-different-random-seeds-for-noise-texture-node/) into the scale or translation to distort it.  The math Multiply nodes above adjust the strength of the distortion.  Here is what the above node setup produces:

[image]

Comment: Very nice stuff!