# How to expose a value that doesn't have an input socket next to it in a Node Group?

Tags: node-editor, drivers

In other words: How to control a value (that doesn't have a socket) in a node inside a Node Group using this Node Group's Group Input.

I'm guessing somehow drivers need to be involved, haven't found info on this though.

Example: Driving a Size property from Map Value node from a Group Input of the Node Group the Map Value node is in.

Comment: What value do you want to add to your group?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/40770/5705

Comment: I don't believe it is possible to drive something from an output socket.  AFAIK you will have to manually recreate the functionality of whatever node you are trying to control as I did in my answer to the above linked question.

Comment: Drivers inside node groups have problems updating, I think somewhere on SE there is a very similar question. The best solution is to build custom nodes that do what exactly you need, rather than trying to hack existing nodes with drivers. If this is possible depends on what you are after. Can you specify it?

Comment: Specified the question with an example. How about linking the Input Socket to a value that then in turn can drive something?

Comment: Driving values with other values seems to be possible: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?260721-Blender-Tutorial-Driving-multiple-values-in-the-compositor-with-one-value

Comment: Looks like we're getting close to a postable answer ;-)