# How to make a barcode like stripes texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor

How could I make this sort of texture using nodes as opposed to assigning materials to faces?

[image]

Specifically, I would like to be able to scale this in a *Node Group*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Shady's Answer works only in this scene and not only in all,So you will have to edit values per scene.

And that's why I prefer using some math Instead.

To get information about our object we will use the texture coordinates node,and use ***Generated*** coordinates.

Suppose you want the strips to be vertically,then you should use the Z axis only of the coordinates and that is by using ***Separate XYZ*** node.

Now let's do the math,I will first multiply the Z axis by a variable integer which is equal to the number of black or white strips.

Then I will *Modulo* the result by 1,Which means I repeat the gradient every 1,and since we multiplied the axis by "say 5" then we will repeat 5 times.

Now we have a number of gradients,I will limit them to be either white or black using ***Greater than*** node.

Here the node tree:
[image: Node tree]

Which will produce the following result:

[image: GIF]

I can group it and expose the variable,and we got our node group:

[image: Node group]

Answer (score 8):

An alternative solution allowing to have regular strips or barcode like strips.

[image]

Here is the node group setup :

[image]

**Group inputs**

- Mapping vector coordinates
- Scale of the strips
- Mode to switch from barcode mode (0) to regular strips (1)

**Group output**

- a factor between 0 and 1. Or exactly 0 or 1 if the mode input above is 0 or 1

**In red** is a separate XYZ because we will rely on X value and don't use the Y value : this will give vertical strips. If you want to have horizontal or other, just change the input vector with a mapping, for instance.

**The green part** is for the barcode (left to right) :

- We recombine the input vector but eliminate the Y value
- A noise texture : the noise is stretched along Y as Y is 0
- The noise texture is scaled by the scale input
- A greater than to obtain 0 if the value is less than 0.5 and 1 if the value is above 0.5 : that gives the strips.

**The blue part** is for the regular strips (left to right) :

- A scale factor by PI (=3.14159). This previous scale factor is chosen, because we take a sinus to obtain a variation from -1 to 1
- A multiplication by the X vector coordinate
- The sinus
- A greater than to obtain 0 if the value is less than 0 and 1 if the value is above 0 : that gives the strips.

**In yellow** a mix node which takes into account the mode we want : 0 for barcode like strips and 1 for regular strips.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Good question! I prefer to use a *Checker Texture* and a *Vector > Mapping* node.

[image]

Note the small *Scale: > X:* value. It is what turns the *Checker Texture* into stripes. Also note that I used *Generated Texture Coordinates*. This works for most simple objects and eliminates tiresome *UV Mapping*. This node setup produces the following result when applied to a plane.

[image]

Note the orientation suggested by the three axes in the bottom lefthand corner of the *3D Viewport*. In a different orientation, you may have to toy with the *Scale: > Y:* or *Scale: > Z:* values. Also note that as you increase the *Checker Texture > Scale:* value, you may have to decrease the affected *Mapping > Scale:* value.

Unfortunately, the *Mapping > Scale:* values cannot be accessed inside a NodeGroup.

Comment: Additionally you may also use a *Gradient* texture or a *Wave* texture, both run through a color ramp node set to *Constant* interpolation

Comment: See also: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/58428/24007