# How can we create a Bar code with the Texture Node Editor?

Tags: compositing-nodes

I had seen a post about how to create lines but one of the Answers by Lemon was excellent.. He used the Shader Node Editor to create a Barcode Generator.

Here is the Link: [How to make a barcode like stripes texture](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58691/how-to-make-a-barcode-like-stripes-texture)

I would love to be able to recreate this within the Texture Node editor. I tried to adapt it but it's not the same..

Comment: Blender 2.8x 2.9 has any Texture node system? Or are you looking for 2.79 creation?

Answer (score -1):

[image]
*waaow!!* here is a zany bar code shader for eevee simpletons such as i

Comment: The question refers to the Texture nodes editor: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/texture_node/introduction.html, not the shader editor.

Comment: This is good But I need it to be in the Texture Node Editor not the Shader Editor..