# Rotate (generated) UVs of environment texture without mapping node

Tags: uv, node-editor, vector-mapping

I'm trying to rotate an environment texture (around Z), but without the mapping node, as it lacks sockets.

I've successfully rebuilt, the node tree detailed here: [Use another node to control Vector Mapping](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58426/use-another-node-to-control-vector-mapping/58428#comment187188_58428)

Works great for Object UVs, but not for generated UVs of an environment map.
I've tried translating it along U, which also didnt work. Any suggestions?

**edit**: the linked node tree works for environment maps, **IF** you connect the Z channel from the initial separate node to the final combine node.

Comment: In what way did it not work? - this might give a clue as to what’s going wrong. Can you edit your post to include your current (not working) node setup so that people can replicate your setup. One thing, bear in mind thst the environment is effectively at infinity - so translation will not work - it’s all about angle of incidence compared to the normal from an infinite sphere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a node setup for a z-axis rotation.  The other 2 axis' are just as easy but adding all three axis' into one formula gets very complicated.

To rotate the image, adjust the Value node that is located at the top-left in the "Deg 2 Rad" frame.

Note: The math nodes all have two "value" fields but only the upper field is used for trigonometry so just ignore any values in the lower fields.

[image]

Comment: This one works on environment maps as well. Thank you so much Marc!