# Scale Texture with a Value-/Math-Node

Tags: texturing, node-editor, vector-mapping

in my node setup I have a value node. I want this node to influence the scaling of my mapping node.

Is there a way to achieve this? Or is there a math/vector node setup I can use to manipulate the scale of my texture?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbv03.gif]

---

I found an answer to my question:
[Possible to control a Driver from a Group Node input slider?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40770/possible-to-control-a-driver-from-a-group-node-input-slider?rq=1)

Because the original question here is another one, I won't delete my post. Maybe it is helpful for someone.

Comment: You might find Bartek Skorupa's explanation useful; [Manipulate texture coordinates like a boss](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kAUmLcXhUj0&t=1402s)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you only want to scale the texture, you can use a *MixRGB* node set to *Multiply* instead of the *Mapping* node, as in this example:

[image]

Comment: Well, thats even easier and with less nodes than the answer I found 10 seconds ago. thanks a lot