# How to multiply vector by scalar in material nodes?

Tags: materials, node-editor, mathematics

I'd like to do arbitrary vector math with the camera position, shading point, and possibly other points. As a test case ([blend file](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=45078)), suppose I want to make a shader that will draw a simple gradient based on distance from the shading point to the camera in one of two ways.

The two methods of getting the desired distance are:

1. "Camera Data.View Distance" as the control.
2. Computing the length of a vector equal to the unit vector given by "Camera Data.View Vector" multiplied by the scalar "Camera Data.View Distance". This is the issue.

The node setup looks like this:

[image]

**What can I put in the "Vec * Scalar?" frame** so that the material will look the same no matter how the "Selector" Mix Shader Factor is set?

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should think more about the data types. If you want vector*scalar, use *MixRGB* set to *Multiply* (an RGB color has three components, like a vector), and not a simple *scalar* math node. See my answer to this question for an example of vector*scalar: [Scale Texture with a Value-/Math-Node](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71163/scale-texture-with-a-value-math-node)

Also your selector seems to be a Mix Shader (I didn't download your file, but it has shader inputs and outputs), and you should not put scalars into a node that expects shaders.

**EDIT** Just for completeness: There are also other ways of doing vector*scalar, like using a vector *Mapping* node and setting the same X, Y, Z Scale, or separating the vector components with a *Separate XYZ* and multiplying the three scalar coordinates individually, and merging them again with *Combine XYZ*.

Comment: MixRGB only does vector*scalar in the 0-1 range, otherwise you have to use vector*vector. It also doesn't accept negative constants. Mapping is only vector*vector constant. Separate XYZ seems to be the best solution; just stick it in a group and copy it around.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using [Open Shading Language](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/osl.html), it's pretty easy to do make a script node that does vector component multiplication:

```
shader osl_vector_multiply(
    vector InVector1 = 1,
    vector InVector2 = 1,
    float InScalar = 1,
    output vector OutVector = 1)
{
    OutVector = InVector1 * InVector2 * InScalar;
}
```